# Algorithms for only compressing static data?

Tags: algorithm, compression, number-theory

What algorithms are designed to compress static data? For example, I have a input string of "Hello world!" I want to make a library that will JIT compile a set of compression and decompression functions for that "Hello World" string. What algorithms are out there that I can learn from? The closest thing I have found so far is the term "Tailed Compression" but I cant find any actual algorithms for this / code.

Comment: Could **zip** help you?

Comment: `a library that will JIT compile a set of compression and decompression functions for [a static string]` What is to be the result of each such function? What do you propose as a measure of quality? Are you aware of [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)? (Did you mean *Tailored Compression*? (No pun intended))

Answer (score 0):

For static (fixed, known at outset) content, you can look at "off-line algorithms". One classification for "*Data compression via textual substitution*" was published in 1982 by J.A. Storer and T.G. Szymanski, in particular "*Off-Line Compression: The Macro Model*".

Answer (score 0):

DEFLATE supports the use of preset dictionaries. These 32kb dictionaries are used as a reference for deduplicating your data.

Very high compression ratios can be achieved on short data strings with recurring patterns by choosing a decent dictionary. (just a concatenation of sample data is often a good start).

You can use [dicflate](https://github.com/hrobeers/dicflate) to experiment with it.